# How to hide an UI Element slowly

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a subView that I want to toggle between hidden and not hidden by a button. How do I fade in the subview and fade it out? For now it just appears immediately and disappear immediately when I toggle the button.

I am wondering what is the easiest way to do this animation. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iOS 4.0+ Apple recommends you use their new, block-based animation methods. Using these, the code would look something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
 animations:^{myView.alpha = 0.0;}];
```

The properties you are animating go inside the block (the `^{...}` part). Blocks are sort of like functions, so you can put multiple lines of code inside of them, if you want to animate multiple properties. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
 animations:^{
  view.alpha = 0.0;
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 }];
```

If you need to perform an action after the animation is complete, use the `+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method (which also uses blocks), for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
 animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

For more info, check out the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) 'Animations' section and 'Animating Views with Blocks' section.

Answer (score 2):

This is the old pre-4.0 way:

http://objcolumnist.com/2009/07/18/simple-uiview-based-animations-on-the-iphone/

... which has the advantage of being conceptually simple and easy to implement.

```
float alpha = 1.0; // or 0.0 if it's already visible and you want to fade out
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0]; // seconds, not ms. guess how i know?
[mySubView setAlpha:alpha];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: That works great, but is there a way to control the rate of animation? For now it is still a bit fast. Thanks

Comment: Adjust the `setAnimationDuration` float value to extend/shorten the animation `[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];`

Comment: Thanks, `dredful`. I felt like something was missing there. :)